# Is the constellation program back on track?

Tags: constellation-program

According to [this article](http://www.space-travel.com/reports/Constellation_is_Back_999.html) the [Constellation program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_program) is funded again.

> Finally, just last Friday President Obama signed a new federal spending bill into law. This bill includes money to continue NASA's human space exploration program. Surprisingly, the exploration program being funded is a program long thought dead by the space community.

Where can there one find an official confirmation of this milestone in US human space exploration?

Comment: [Orion carries on from the Constellation program](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/constellation/orion/index.html), but that article you link to is littered with misinformation. For one, it's attaching an image showing that NASA's next big step in space exploration launch vehicle is the concept [ATK-Astrium Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_(rocket)) rocket using [Ares I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_I) first stage, which is simply ridiculous. It's just a badly written article and the image caption _"File image."_ should alert you to that fact fast enough. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article you link to seems to be shooting from the hip, with no evidence to back it up.
Spacepolitics has a more [comprehensive overview](http://www.spacepolitics.com/2014/01/14/omnibus-bill-gives-nasa-17-65-billion-and-launch-indemnification-extension-as-well/) of NASA's budget. They list \$1.6 billion for the Space Launch System and nearly \$1.2 billion for Orion. No mention of Constellation.
Feel free to read the official text of the [2014 spending bill](http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/bdquery/z?d113%3ah.r.03547%3a), but it's 600+ pages of legalese to wade through (and no mention of Constellation, at least not by name).
[Space.com](http://www.space.com/11411-nasa-2011-budget-cuts-constellation-funding.html) says that NASA is now free to end the remaining Constellation contracts. Since 2011, the odd situation existed that NASA could not legally end some contracts, despite Constellation being cancelled.